# Why is there an extra line in the file I am writing?

Tags: java, file, arraylist

How can i read all name of username from text file and write it into new text file. There are no compilation errors, but my output is incorrect. Help me find out the problem or give me a example. Thank you.

The file resident.txt:

```
  james|123
  kelvin|123
```

Expected result:

```
 fee.txt
 jan|james
 jan|kelvin
```

My end result:

```
 fee.txt
 jan|james
 jan|kelvin
 jan|
```

The source:

```
private void btnConfirmActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    boolean flag = false;
    File file = new File("resident.txt");
    ArrayList al = FileFunction.getContent(file);
    for (Object obj : al) {
        String newobj = obj.toString();
        String s[] = newobj.split("\\|");

        String strMonth = txtMonth.getSelectedItem().toString();
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("fee.txt", true))) {
            out.println(strMonth + "|" + s[0]);
            flag = true;
            new ClerkPage(txtUsername.getText()).setVisible(true);
            this.dispose(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } 
    }
    if(flag){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Monthly fee was successfully charged! ");
    }
}
```

FileFunction.java

```
package data;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileFunction {

    public static ArrayList getContent(File f) {
        ArrayList ls = null;
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));) {
            String line;
            ls = new ArrayList();
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                ls.add(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ls;
    }

    public static boolean setContent(String oldInput, String newInput, File f) {
        boolean isDone = false;
        //temp bag
        ArrayList tempLs = null;
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);) {
            tempLs = new ArrayList();
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String tempLine = scan.nextLine();
                //check if it s the same with old..
                if (tempLine.equals(oldInput)) {
                    tempLs.add(newInput);                    
                } else {
                    tempLs.add(tempLine);
                }
            }
            if (makeNewContent(tempLs, f)) {
                isDone = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isDone;
    }

    private static boolean makeNewContent(ArrayList newContent, File f) {

        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (Object object : newContent) {
                sb.append(object);
                sb.append("\r\n");
            }
            addContent(sb.toString(), f, false);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static boolean addContent(String input, File f, boolean append) {
        boolean isDone = false;
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f, append))) {
            out.print(input);
            isDone = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return isDone;
    }

    public static boolean removeContent(String oldInput, File f) {
        boolean isDone = false;
        ArrayList tempLs = null;
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
            tempLs = new ArrayList();
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.equals(oldInput)) {
                    continue;
                }
                tempLs.add(line);
            }
            if (f.exists()) {
                f.delete();
            }
            if (makeNewContent(tempLs, f)) {
                isDone = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isDone;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the source for `FileFunction.getContent` as the problem is probably there. As a side note: Don't use raw types. Use `ArrayList<String>`, not `ArrayList`, and use for with a `String` variable, not an `Object`, so you won't need to use `obj.toString()`.

Comment: You should read [this excellent blog post by Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) on how to debug small program such as yours.

Comment: @RealSkeptic i already post my filefunction.java? i dont know hw to use arraylist<string>. Can give me an example

Comment: Is there a newline at the end of your source file? Maybe `getContent` should handle that.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann sorry, i dont understand your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a newline at the end of `resident.txt`. I tried your code with a mock text file, and I reproduced your problem when I added an extra (blank) line at the bottom of `resident.txt`. You can get around this by adding this modification to `FileFunction.getContent()`:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
        ls.add(line);
    }
}
```

As others have noted, you should change the way in which you are creating your `ArrayList`s :

```
ArrayList ls = null; // wrong
ArrayList<String> ls = null; // correct
ls = new ArrayList<String>(); // can do "new ArrayList<>();" if you're using Java 8

public static ArrayList getContent(File f) // wrong
public static ArrayList<String> getContent(File f) // correct
```

You get the idea. The space in between the `< >` brackets is where you put the type of object that will be stored in the array. Same goes for `Map`, `Collection`, etc.